# Could please provide me with the correct syntax so I can cross reference? Thank you very much! :)

Tags: c

Implement a C file with the name `Greetings.c`.

Its header file `Greetings.h` should look like:

```
#ifndef GREETINGS_H_INCLUDED
#define GREETINGS_H_INCLUDED

void writeMessage();

#endif // GREETINGS_H_INCLUDED
```

The function `writeMessage` should print on the screen the message:

> I am happy to be here!

Number of times equal to the number of letters in your last name.

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried so far? SO isn't a homework service. You *must* to **include your [Minimum Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** Please Read: [What kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), and
[Research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Then `edit` to get help.

Comment: What is the concrete problem you are facing? What isn't working?

Comment: I am a total beginner in C .. so I'm trying to figure out if what I'm doing is correct !! Please be patient with me :)

Comment: Your function declaration doesn’t provide a prototype for the function. It needs to be `void writeMessage(void);` to be a prototype, assuming the function takes no argument.  So, it is not showing good practices because of that.

Comment: Thank you!! perhaps that was it. Sheryl my sincerest apologies :) All the people tell me here in Italy that girls cannot code !! That's why I picked programming :) :)

Comment: **Future Tip**: please avoid capital letters in file names. Some file systems are case sensitive and file name case mismatching is a source of portability issues. Avoid portability bugs by always naming files and folders using lower case.

Comment: Note that if the function needs to know how many times to write its message, you really need to pass it a number, which your main program will calculate from the length of your name. That means you’ll need the name from somewhere; either a command line argument or reading from standard input, possibly after prompting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Greetings.h"

void writeMessage()
{
    printf("I am happy to be here!\n");
}


int main()
{
    printf("Please enter your last name: ");

    char lastName[100];

    if (fgets(lastName, sizeof(lastName), stdin))
    {
        for (int i = 0; lastName[i] != 0; ++i)
        {
            if (!isalpha(lastName[i])) // count only letters
                continue;

            writeMessage();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```